# Specializing member function template of a non-template class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, overloading, function-templates

Is the following specialization of the member function template `bar` valid? It compiles on gcc 4.5.3 and VS .NET 2008. I'm confused because I vaguely recall reading that function templates cannot be specialized.

```
struct Foo
{
    template<typename T>
    void bar();
};

template<typename T>
void Foo::bar(){}

template<>
void Foo::bar<bool>(){}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.bar<char>();
    f.bar<bool>();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function template can not be partially specialized, but can be explicitly specialized, your code is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 0):

Function template partial specialization [was considered in C++11 but was rejected](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#229) since function template overloading can be used to solve the same issue. However, there're [some caveats](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm) which have to be looked for when doing this.

Example:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T);
void foo(int);

foo(10);   // calls void bar(int)
foo(10.f); // calls void bar(T) [with T = float]
foo(10u);  // calls void bar(T) [with T = unsigned int]!!
```

For your case, something of this sort might work

```
struct Foo
{
    template<typename T>
    void bar(T dummy);

    void bar(bool dummy);
};

template<typename T>
void Foo::bar(T dummy) { }

void Foo::bar(bool dummy) { }

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.bar('a');
    f.bar(true);
}
```